# Created file disappears when Android app is killed programatically

Tags: android, file

I am creating a file in Android:

```
        File eFile = new File("/data/user/0/myapp/WeANDSF/E1"); 
        eFile.createNewFile();
```

This works perfectly and I can see the file in the device file explorer in AS.
If I kill the using "Force Stop" then all is okay and the file remains there.

However, if I kill it using one of:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
    System.exit(0);
```

The file disappears.

The reason I need to kill the app is complicated.

Why is my file disappearing?

Comment: "This works perfectly" -- that code will not compile. `"myfilename;` is not a valid string, and a string is not a `File`. It will be difficult for people to help you debug your code when they do not have the actual code that needs to be debugged. "However, if I kill it using one of" -- I am uncertain why you expect reliable results from anything when you terminate your process that way. Regardless, if I create a file using `createNewFile()` in `getFilesDir()`, and I terminate the process using `System.exit(0)`, the file remains intact.

Comment: Yeah. I kinda shortened it. But my main point is that the file is created and yet disappears when I kill with System.exit(0). But it doesn't disappear when I exit normally, restart the device in the middle or kill the app from "Force Close".

Comment: "I kinda shortened it" -- in this case, apparently the details matter. Perhaps you could try creating your file in some other location, such as `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated it with the exact filepath+name

Comment: That path is not always valid. Perhaps you could try creating your file in some other location, such as `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: But it does create the file. It just disappears afterwards.

Comment: If I create a file using `createNewFile()` in `getFilesDir()`, and I terminate the process using `System.exit(0)`, the file remains intact. That was tested on a Pixel 4 running Android 11. You might try reproducing that experiment. If that works, then your problem is tied at least in part to your choice of storage location, and perhaps a different location will work better for you. If that experiment fails, then there is a difference in our environments that causes it to work for me.

Comment: I'll give it shot